# ManyToOneField in Django

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to define a many-to-one field in the class that is the "Many".  For example,  imagine a situation where a user can only be a member of one group but a group can have many users:

```
class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    # This is what I want to do -> users = models.ManyToOneField(User)
```

Django docs will tell to define a group field in the User model as a ForeignKey, but I need to define the relationship in the Group model.  As far as I know, there isn't a ManyToOneField and I would rather not have to use a ManyToManyField.

Comment: Why can't you use ForeignKey?

Comment: I'm working off an existing project and don't want to make changes to the base models that the main project continues to update.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A `ManyToOne` field, as you've guessed, is called `ForeignKey` in Django. You will have to define it on your `User` class for the logic to work properly, but Django will make a reverse property available on the `Groups` model automatically:

```
class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)

class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group)

g = Group.objects.get(id=1)
print g.user_set.all()  # prints list of all users in the group
```

Remember that Django's models sit on top of a relational database... there's no way to define a single FK field in a table that points to more than one foreign key (without a M2M, that is), so putting the ManyToOne relationship on the Groups object doesn't map to the underlying data store. If you were writing raw SQL, you'd model this relationship with a foreign key from the user table to the group table in any event, if it helps to think of it that way. The syntax and logic of using a `ManyToOne` property that is defined on a Group instance, if such a concept existed, would be much less straightforward than the ForeignKey defined on User.

Comment: Thanks for explaining why it wasn't possible to do what I was looking for.  I'm just going to use a many to many field.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the Users construct is the built-in authentication system... I would recommend creating a Profile model of some sort and attaching the OneToMany field to it instead.  You can then [hook the Profile model to the user model](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#storing-additional-information-about-users).

Answer (score 1):

You should probably be looking at simply using built in reverse lookups:

```
group = Group.objects.get(id=1)
users_in_group = group.user_set.all()
```

Reverse lookup sets are automatically created for any foreign keys or many-to-many relationships to the model in question.

If you want to refer to this with a friendlier name, or provide additional filtering before returning, you can always wrap the call in a method:

```
class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)

    def users(self):
        return self.user_set.all()
```

Either can be called from the templates:

```
{{ group.user_set.all }}

{{ group.users }}
```

Comment: Thanks!  This is what I'm using with the ManyToMany field in the Group class.